# Erlang uncatchable exception

Tags: exception, erlang

I have the following code in Erlang, in which I'm mecking an nonexistent module.
In some versions of Erlang/meck this generates an exception that seems uncatchable.

Anyone knows if there is an "uncatchable exception" feature in Erlang ?

```
try
    meck:new(i_dont_exist),
    io:format("No exception in this version of Erlang ... :( "),
    no_problems
catch
    exit:_ -> exit;
    error:_ -> error;
    throw:_ -> throw;
    _:_ -> what_class_is_it
    after
        io.format("in the after~n")
end.
```

When I execute this code this is what I get (notice that not even the "after" clause is being executed so it looks more like a bug to me):

```
** exception exit: {undefined_module,i_dont_exist}
     in function  meck_proc:resolve_can_expect/3 (src/meck_proc.erl, line 402)
     in call from meck_proc:init/1 (src/meck_proc.erl, line 194)
     in call from gen_server:init_it/6 (gen_server.erl, line 304)
     in call from proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3 (proc_lib.erl, line 227)
```

I have also tried with the "catch" expression with the same result:

```
> catch meck:new(i_dont_exist).
** exception exit: {undefined_module,i_dont_exist}
     in function  meck_proc:resolve_can_expect/3 (src/meck_proc.erl, line 402)
     in call from meck_proc:init/1 (src/meck_proc.erl, line 194)
     in call from gen_server:init_it/6 (gen_server.erl, line 304)
     in call from proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3 (proc_lib.erl, line 227)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's happening here is that `meck:new` spawns a new process (a `gen_server` process using the `meck_proc` callback module), and that process exits with the `undefined_module` error.  (You can get it not to do that by passing the `non_strict` option to `meck:new`.)  This new process is *linked* to the calling process, which means that an exit signal will be sent to the calling process, and the calling process will exit as well, without being able to `catch` the signal.

You can avoid that by making your calling process trap exits:

```
process_flag(trap_exit, true)
```

which will turn the exit signal into a message that you can `receive`; see [the manual](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/processes.html) for more details.  However, as a general rule you should avoid trapping exits, as it makes error handling more complicated (as opposed to the default "crash, restart").